# session null does not exist (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am actually new to selenium, I have automated the website successfully using Firefox driver but when I tried the same code in IE am getting the subjected error in the driver.get(URL) line I used two different type simple code to open the browser and navigate to google which is not working.

please help me resolve this issue with IEDriver.

code 1:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\otherdata\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
```

code 2:

```
DesiredCapabilities IEcaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    IEcaps .setCapability(
    InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
    true);
    File SrcFile= new File("D:\\other data\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", SrcFile.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IEcaps );
    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

**ERROR:**

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.5.1.0
Listening on port 5424
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session null does not exist (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'MGK-PC', ip: '192.168.1.108', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{capabilities={acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:5424/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss, platformName=windows, setWindowRect=true}, sessionId=668e028c-b9e5-4ddc-8d0a-f2d61ac62bde, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
    at New.IE_Test.main(IE_Test.java:27)
```

Comment: It is important have the correct Selenium and the webdriver version for your IE version installed. Could you put the versions are you using?

Comment: @j.barrio iam using selenium-java-2.53.1 , IE 11 and IEDriverServer_Win32_3.5.1.

Comment: Maybe you should update the selenium version. The latest version is the  [3.6.0](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). And update the webdrivers from all the browsers. Or download the correct version for the [IE webdriver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).